# How to filter by several class name in opencover and report generator in bat

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, batch-file, opencover

> How to filter by several class name in opencover and report generator in bat file

It is necessary to receive only those classes in namespace

> *.AutomapperConfigurators.* or ProjectName.BL.ServiceInteraction.*

for opencover

> -filter:"+*.AutomapperConfigurators.*;+ProjectName.BL.ServiceInteraction*

for report generator

> -classfilters:"+*.AutomapperConfigurators.*;+ProjectName.BL.ServiceInteraction]*

it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for opencover you need to use the [filters](https://github.com/opencover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters) correctly.

for the example given your filters should probably look like this

```
-filter:"+[*]*.AutomapperConfigurators.* +[*]ProjectName.BL.ServiceInteraction.*"
```

once the opencover filters are correct you don't need to apply [m]any reportgenerator filters.